# JavaScript IntelliSense with Reference Path in Visual Studio 2019 no more working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

As I noticed, IntelliSense with "Reference Path"-File comment's are no longer supported in Visual Studio 2019. We recently switched from 2017 to Version 2019.

Reference Path example: `/// <reference path="../Messages.js" />`

Unfortunately, my Team and I working still a lot with plain JavaScript files.
Is there any chance to enable the old IntelliSense behavior?

Comment: It should still work. You may have accidentally converted your `.js` files to modules (do you see any `import` or `export` statements in any `.js` files? They can be added by VS automatically simply by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in the wrong place).

Comment: Also, what project-type are you working in?

Comment: It is a Web Project Type with .NET 4.5. 
We don't have any import export statement's within the files :-(